# OAuth/OpenID and stateless applications

Tags: security, oauth, session-cookies, plotly-dash, openid

My team and I are developing a Dash application that is supposed to provide log-in functionality based on my company's OpenID service. While we managed to take the first steps and a) set a session cookie and b) get an authentication token from the OpenID server, I'm a but uncertain about the next steps. This is the first web app I'm developing, so bare with me if some of the following is a bit vague. The main goal of having the user log in is two-fold. 1) They should be known to the organization and 2) we have to identify in which group the user is (there are two groups, more to come). The authentication token contains the group membership, so that works in principle. However,
our security expert told us that the cookie should not contain any information about the group membership in order to meet our security standards, but a "client sided session cookie" is okay. I have two questions about that.

1. Why would I assume that a session cookie is safe but I shouldn't trust any additional information it contains. The cookie is signed by the server and any kind of manipulation seems difficult to me.
2. From an architectural point of view this seems to compromise the idea of stateless web apps. If I can't store the group membership on the client side I have to set up a database with log in information and each single HTTP request to the web app entails a lookup, so I feel like I'm ending up with a single point of failure and a performance bottleneck. Is this really how larger (web) apps do it?

Comment: this seems like a case where you're better off using an authenticating reverse proxy in front of you application rather than implementing OIDC/OAuth yourself; see e.g. https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/ which takes care of the issues that you mention

Comment: That's an interesting concept, thank you for pointing it out! I'll check it out. Perhaps it's my lucky day and the company has something like that already implemented somewhere..